# Can IBM Watson Assistant use more than one webhook

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, watson-assistant-solutions

I am making a chat bot that requires the use of **3 external APIs** to be used as responses. When wanting to call an external API from within Watson Assistant, webhooks would be required to connect to one API either locally or on the cloud (IBM functions). How would I connect more than one API to the assistant if possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, not at this time. The design was meant to have a middleware app that orchestrated the apis, formats the data, etc just like the video in the docs.

Comment: What middleware app would you suggest ? Something like ibm functions ?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, you could use an IBM function, to then call your different external API's, depending on a "trigger" added to the call data. i.e. Call API 1. etc. You would also understand which format/layout to return the data. You could even have your IBM function call different IBM functions, which each only then work with one of the external API's.  This would make the process easier to expand and maintain.